# In Guidewire testing framework, as part of ignite setup, "gwb compile" command not recognizing

Tags: guidewire

I am using Hakuba version and trying to setup ignite, but when I execute the "gwb compile" command, getting "'gwb' is not recognized as an internal or external command" I ran this command from the root folder of the framework.
The same details are mentioned in GW documentation, please let me know your thoughts on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running `gwb` in the wrong directory. It must be run in the root folder of your Guidewire app installation. Once the compile is successful it will generate a jar file in the `xCenterAppProjectFolder/modules/configuration/build/libs/configuration-x.0.x.jar` directory.

Here's the documentation explanaing this step https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/testing/202306/ui/gw-ui/topics/c_running_ignite.html (Requires Login).

You must make sure there is a `gwb.bat` (Windows) or a `gwb.sh` (Unix) present in your project install directory. In case these files were removed or tampered with, the `gwb` command won't be recognized.